# fluent asynchronous function javascript >es8

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I try hard to get a fluent interface with asynchronous functions.
I have something like that:

```
class aClass {

    async asyncFuntionA() {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 100);
        })
        console.log('Funcion A')
    }
    async asyncFuntionB() {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 300);
        })
        console.log('Funcion B')
    }
}
```

Now I want to call them like that:

```
var test = new aClass();
test.asyncFuntionB().asyncFuntionA()
```

or

```
var test = new aClass();
test.funtionB().funtionA()
```

where `functionA` and `functionB` are some synchronous functions which need to achieve my goal for the asynchronous functions.

Comment: What's wrong with `await (await test.asyncFuntionB()).asyncFuntionA()`?

Comment: Because I have a very long list of functions, which should be called synchronously and want to provide an easy api.

Comment: And they all shall be chained after each other? Do they need to pass around any state?

Comment: state would be cool in future but they need to be chained

Comment: @t.niese Probably that will do it. Now I have to understand that, but it seems to fit.

Comment: yeah, I think this question could be marked as doubled. -.- I didn't found the question.